# VMware write eager zeros after disk creation

Tags: vmware-esxi

It would be nice to be able to convert a Lazy Zeroed disk to an Eager Zeroed disk after disk creation in VMware - is this possible?

I understand the basic difference between [*Thick Provision Lazy Zeroed* and *Thick Provision Eager Zeroed*](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc_50%2FGUID-4C0F4D73-82F2-4B81-8AA7-1DD752A8A5AC.html).  I usually want to do Lazy Zero so I can create the disk faster.  And the eager zeroed performance increase is not large in most circumstances.

However, it would be nice to make the disk Eager Zeroed after disk creation, perhaps as a background task.

Comment: If you have multiple datastores then you should be able to convert the disk by migrating the VM storage to another datastore and selecting the appropriate disk format. Then simply migrate it back to the original datastore.

Comment: I'm curious what type of environment still requires thick-provisioned disks.

Comment: @ewwhite thick provisioning isn't required, but possibly desired

Comment: Sure. I understand @steampowered. But add the context to the question if you can. It may be interesting to note use cases where thick-provisioning is beneficial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `vmkfstools` with the -k option. For example:

```
vmkfstools -k disk.vmdk
```

However, you will have to shutdown the VM first and login to the ESXi Shell.

Also, to determine if a disk is zeroedthick or eagerzeroedthick, you can use the same command with the -D parameter as:

```
vmkfstools -D disk.vmdk
```

Then look for `tbz 0` in the resulting output. If the value is 0 then the disk is `eagerzeroedthick`, otherwise it is `zeroedthick`.

Both commands are described in the follwing VMware KB article:

[Determining if a VMDK is zeroedthick or eagerzeroedthick (1011170)](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1011170)

Answer (score 2):

Storage vMotion or a powered-off datastore migration will allow you to select a different disk type.  Then just migrate the disk back to the original datastore, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

If your VM is running Linux you can use the Zerofree tool to do this.  Keep in mind if your running this on the root filesystem you'll first need to mount it as read-only.  The Zerofree man page explains how to do this.  It's pretty simple.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using windows you can use sdelete as part of the sysinternals toolkit or (faster) the Nimble space reclaim powershell which will zero out the free space